# How to run tkinter inside odoo application

Tags: python, tkinter, odoo, odoo-15

I am running Odoo15 and i want to use python tkinter library in the odoo on remote linux server.

when i am running a simple code in my odoo application like

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

i am getting the below error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

My first query or doubt is whether it is possible to use tkinter with odoo application on remote linux server ??

If yes please let me know how i can solve this error.
I have seen many answers for this same error on internet but none of them worked for me so far.
I'll be looking forward to hear on this ... Thanks

Comment: If you want to run the application on a remote computer... where do you expect the GUI to be displayed? I have no idea what odoo is but can you not use the SSH -X command to forward the display to your local machine? Perhaps you can share what you have tried already.

Comment: @scotty3785   Odoo is a web based application and i have used tkinter library in it. when i run it to my localhost (localhost server for Odoo), it runs well without a problem. Then i installed tkinter library on my remote server (linux) where other users will access this through the web but when i run the same code on the remote server i am getting the error in log that i mentioned above. i tried some commands suggested on other platforms to set the $DISPLAY variable but none of them worked for me.  I want to run the tkinter on the remote server by using a $DISPLAY of the remote server itself.

Comment: By the way your suggestion to forward the display to local, in that case there may be many users accessing my server and would it be possible to forward DISPLAY to localhost computer dynamically ?                


Basically i have created a python interpreter to run python codes dynamically on my server. So to deal with user inputs like
val= input("Enter val")
i am using tkinter so i can replace this line with tkinter code and a popup could be open to take user inputs.


Key question is tkinter using for desktop apps, how would it be possible to use this on a web based remote server ?

Comment: Tkinter is not well suited for this multi-user, web based application.

Comment: Well, i respect your answer but actually i have applied a solution for this approach so i would like to give all possibilities to do so.     If you have understood what i had done so far and what i am liking to do,  can you please help me out to do so  ?

Comment: Also if anyone have idea what could be an alternative way to do such graphical operations on multi users web based application ..... like a popup to take some texts from users   ?